# Visual Studio 2017 installer keeps telling me "elevation required"?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-10, visual-studio-2017, administrator

When I try to install VS 2017 on a machine, the installer gives me the following error despite the fact that I'm already an administrator (yes I've tried "Run as Administrator" and messing with UAC etc... trust me I've tried all the usual stuff and know how Windows works):

> Elevation Required
>
> This program requires administrator privileges to perform setup operations.
> Please rerun the program as administrator.

Tracing with ProcMon, I see a log in my temp directory that seems to be indicating the cause:

```
Information : Log configuration: $SERVICEHUBTRACELEVEL=""
Error : HubHost 'desktopClr$C94B8CFE-E3FD-4BAF-A941-2866DBB566FE' PID 3736 stderr: Error running host: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: creationOptions
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task..ctor(Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions, Boolean promiseStyle)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.HostLib.Host..ctor(String hostId, String pipeName, DevHubTraceSource logger)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.HostLib.Program.<MainAsync>d__0.MoveNext()

Error : HubHost 'desktopClr$C94B8CFE-E3FD-4BAF-A941-2866DBB566FE' PID 3736 stderr: 

Error : HubHost 'desktopClr$C94B8CFE-E3FD-4BAF-A941-2866DBB566FE' PID 3736 stderr: Unhandled Exception: 
Error : HubHost 'desktopClr$C94B8CFE-E3FD-4BAF-A941-2866DBB566FE' PID 3736 stderr: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: creationOptions
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task..ctor(Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions, Boolean promiseStyle)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.HostLib.Host..ctor(String hostId, String pipeName, DevHubTraceSource logger)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.HostLib.Program.<MainAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ServiceHub.Host.Program.Main(String[] args)

Error : Error starting service 'SetupEngine.ProductsProvider' requested by ProductsProvider (pid: 3340): Hub host 'desktopClr', PID: 3736 exited. code: '3762504530'.
Error : Error starting service 'SetupEngine.Installer' requested by Installer (pid: 3340): Hub host 'desktopClr', PID: 3736 exited. code: '3762504530'.
```

It seems their code is buggy except this is only happening on my machine? Why isn't everyone seeing this? What's triggering this problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/19601/visual-studio-installer-elevation-required.html

Comment: @sailfish009: Thanks, I already saw that but nothing on there worked. I was indeed on a domain but I even tried leaving it and running that script and also checking to see there weren't any weird policies and still didn't manage to fix it. I know they claim it's fixed on the bottom but I literally just downloaded the VS Preview installer a few hours ago and it didn't work so either their Preview is behind their official release or they haven't fixed it.

Comment: I just ignored this and it still installed fine.

Comment: @niico: There's no way for me to "ignore" it, it just doesn't show me the installation options at all. All I see is Retry/View Log/etc. and of course Retry just repeats the error...

Comment: @Mehrdad New 15.1 update out today - maybe this will fix it?

Comment: @niico: I thought I tried it and it didn't, but not sure... but either way, the update doesn't have Python; the preview does. I want Python...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this by installing [.NET Framework 4.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55167), though I suspect updating 4.0 to even a slightly more recent version might work too.

The issue seemed to be a bug in the `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` class, where it didn't allow passing a flag that was supposed to be legal. I assumed this was a version mismatch and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded VS preview https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/ then it worked fine again

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the cause was the TMP and TEMP environment variables, pointing to non-available paths, on removed drives.